# How long does it take Google to update all links from R 301?

Tags: google, seo

I just changed the location of my blog, and have done the appropriate redirects. Does anyone have knowledge or experience for the delay in updating all the links across Google?

Reason I ask, I wish to change the A record. So this will eliminate the .htaccess file, and thus null and void the redirect.

How long must I wait prior to the undertaking?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There is no set time for when Google will crawl your page. For very large and popular websites they may refresh the index every hour, but for most smaller websites it may take a few weeks for them to re-crawl your page. The best way to make sure that your website is correctly indexed by Google is to use their [Webmaster Tools](http://www.google.com/webmasters/). This will let you view any crawl errors and stats, configure a site map, and even view the page directly as the crawl bot views it.

Answer (score -1):

I totally agree with Greg Bray.

This is just For Your Information.

If your web site is small, meaning it takes a week or even longer for SEs to crawl your site, one way to improve the possibility of attracting them to visit your site earlier is to put your link on other big sites. Be warned though, do not use black hat SEO.

Good luck.